# installing android studio on ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

everybody, I am the android developer, I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Because of some hardware problem, I have to format my PC. before that android studio , SDK and Java were working perfectly.

After formatting my PC. I installed jdk1.8.0_71. after i extract android studio deb file with command `sudo dpkg -i android-studio_4.13.0-ubuntu0_all.deb`
and 'android-studio' folder extracted at /opt directory.

after that, i try to run /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh  with command.

`sh ./studio.sh`  and it gives me error like this  [image: Error picture]

I have also tried by `./studio.sh` to execute but same error. please help to solve.

Comment: Have you tried `openjdk` ?

Comment: Yeah that might solve the problem

Comment: okay let me try, i installed sun java currently.

Comment: I don't remember it well but I think you can install it directly from APT.
`sudo apt-get install android-studio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem bu reinstalling java properly. i thought i installed wrong java/jdk. now Android Studio,Java is working.

I found this link useful to install java step by step. [Link to install java step by step](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Answer (score 1):

To install Oracle Java on Ubuntu, do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I do this every time I install an Android Studio and it works flawlessly. And your Java 8 will be kept up to date, too. The environment variables are automatically properly set by that procedure.

Comment: i exactly installed java with this commands. after that my javac and java command works fine.

Answer (score 1):

its all about ELF execution (when you get bushes in output)

- when your 64 bit os tries to start the Android SDK which in turns tries to run some 32 bit binaries and thus is the issue of compatibility.

check you have  proper libs  installed for studio

```
 sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

> 64-bit architecture  your you need

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:amd64 libstdc++6:amd64 zlib1g:amd64
```

> and 32 bit:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

for details see:

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

ps if apt could not find such libs try to search for similar - the name can vary for different distro

also use proper java hotspot (jdk) 32/64bit for your system

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Android Studio takes just a few clicks.

While the Android Studio download completes, verify which version of the JDK you have: open a command line and type javac -version. If the JDK is not available or the version is lower than 1.8, download the Java SE Development Kit 8.

To install Android Studio on Linux, proceed as follows:

```
Unpack the .zip file you downloaded to an appropriate location for your applications, such as within /usr/local/ for your user profile, or /opt/ for shared users.
To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the android-studio/bin/ directory, and execute studio.sh.

Tip: Add android-studio/bin/ to your PATH environment variable so you can start Android Studio from any directory.
Select whether you want to import previous Android Studio settings or not, then click OK.
The Android Studio Setup Wizard guides you though the rest of the setup, which includes downloading Android SDK components that are required for development.
```

Note: If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

For your details:
https://storage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/videos/studio-install-linux.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with finding java by starting android-studio on ubuntu.
I solved the problems by editing the studio.sh file.

In the file the JAVA_HOME variable should be set, but it wasn't.
So I set the JAVA_HOME variable in the script manually and I could start android-studio.

Comment: where at the end of file? or at specific location. i have variable JAVA_HOME in file, but i think it is not assigned to path

Answer (score 0):

**Install Android Studio in ubuntu :**

1. At first install JDK

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java**

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer**

**sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default**

2. Download the android studio from here

**https://developer.android.com/studio**

3. Unzip android studio tar file using :

**sudo unzip android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip -d /opt**

or Simply unzip the download file using Archive Manager

4. Goto to android-studio/bin folder and open terminal  or in terminal type

**/opt/android-studio/bin**

Then type :

**./studio.sh**

Android studio lunch your computer.

5. It takes about 30 min to one hour to finish gradle.
   There recommend some updates and you should provide those updates.
6. For installing app using your phone, open developer mode. If you cannot see developer options go to about phone and tap build version 8 times.
   In developer options turn on  usb debugging.
7. Connect the phone into the computer using a USB cable.
8. Give a commands : **sudo apt install adb**
9. On the phone there is a dialog for debugging permission. Provide the permission.

Then install the app.

10. For saw the program in desktop goto tools->Create Desktop Entry-> Ok

Answer (score -1):

Please, try to install java 7 or openjdk. It must solve problem.